# How can I specify the number of elements that test positive for the locator I'm using?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium when waiting for an element to load **how can I specify the number of elements that test positive for the locator** I'm using?

This is my case, I want to check for a div of class '*classA*' which contains a text '*text2*':

```
WebDriverWait(driver,3)
    .until(expected_conditions
        .text_to_be_present_in_element(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, 'classA'), 'text2'))
```

but this is going to time out with however long a wait I set, while the previous element also with '*classA*' but with '*text1*' is found without issue.

I think Selenium is locating the previous element based on class, than testing if its text ever changes to '*text2*'.

I want to find the second element based on class, then test for its text (note that *presence_of_all_elements_located* will return as soon as it founds a single positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with custom wait condition using lambda.
For example, in case you want to wait 3 seconds until number of elements will be equal 2:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,3)
   .until(lambda method: len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'className')) == 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it with existing built-in methods in Python.
In Java we have expected conditions like

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(element, expectedElementsAmount));
```

and

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(element,expectedElementsAmount));
```

but these methods are missing in Python.
You can implement such custom methods by yourself in Python

Comment: I ended up using one of the default methods (since either way I would have called the get_all private method already in the code), but I can guarantee writing a custom one should be easy peasy for anyone